# Extract value from array structure

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array structure:

```
array (
  'ALCAR STAHLRAD' => 
  array (
    'diametru' => 
    array (
      0 => 15,
      6 => 16,
      9 => 14,
      14 => 13,
      20 => 17,
      468 => 20,
    ),
...........
```

I was doing that code:

```
$diametru = '';
foreach ($items as $key => $val){
    $diametru .= "<option>$key[array]['diametru']=>$val</option>";
}
print_r($diametru);
```

I was expecting to add into my "option" the "diametru" value

```
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>14</option>
..............
```

but the output is:

A['diametru']=>ArrayE['diametru']=>ArrayD['diametru']=>ArrayD['diametru']...
Thank you in advance for any idea :)

Comment: you have to use a nested foreach to get desired result

Comment: It working just one foreach, I just need key of key value, then again key of key value, but I don't know how to extract that values

Comment: I was trying also: $diametru .= "<option>[$key][$key]=>$val</option>"; but still not extracting the value I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** : If you want to add `array_unique` and `SORT_NUMERIC` then see my edited code.

You can do it through [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) if you don't want to use foreach.

```
$arr = array ( 'ALCAR STAHLRAD' => array ( 'diametru' => array ( 0 => 15, 6 => 16, 7 => 16, 9 => 14, 14 => 13, 20 => 17, 468 => 20, ), ));
$option_arr = array_column($arr,'diametru');
function generate_option($item, $key)
{
    echo "<option>" . $key . " : ". $item . "</option>";
}

$options = array_unique($option_arr[0]); // You can add array_unique and SORT_NUMERIC here

asort($options); // If you want sort by key then you need to use asort. Because array_unique remove duplicate from array but doesn't sort actually.

echo "<select>";
array_walk_recursive($options, 'generate_option');
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Do you have any ideea on your sample where to add "array_unique" and "SORT_NUMERIC"

Comment: Thank you again! The "array_unique" works fine but "SORT_NUMERIC" not :(

Comment: I am using just "<option>" . $item . "</option>", maybe you sorted the $key values

Comment: @Gafwebmaster Do you want sort by key or sort by value?

Comment: I would like to sort by value

Answer (score 0):

Get your 1st element first:

```
$alcar = $items[0]; // ALCAR STAHLRAD
// or
$alcar = $items['ALCAR STAHLRAD'];
```

Then get diameters array:

```
$diameters = $alcar['diametru'];
```

And only then you can do your loop:

```
diametru = '';
foreach ($diameters as $key => $val){
    $diametru .= '<option>'.$key.'=>'.$val.'</option>';
}
print_r($diametru);
```

Comment: The elements name comes dynamic, I don't know the name; it could be also one element or more, I can't go one by one to take and iterate for each.